# req.originalUrl not set by Restify (it is needed by Connect session middleware)

Tags: node.js, session, middleware, restify, node.js-connect

I'm getting an error when I try to use Restify with Connect session middleware.
The session middleware expects req.originalUrl but Restify doesn't set that property. (It only sets req.url.)
That is causing an exception in the session code. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you just set it yourself?

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  req.originalUrl = req.url;
  next();
});
app.use(connect.session({secret:'foo'});
```

Comment: Yes, that works, but is that the recommended fix? Because, using that causes other problems: UncaughtExceptions are not caught by the restify 'uncaughtException' handler and the server shuts down. Is that a separate issue?

Comment: Hmm, no idea! I haven't used Restify myself and I don't know how its error handling works. I know that in Express you can put `function(err, req, res, next)` at the end of your middleware chain to catch unhandled exceptions, but I'm not sure whether that works with Connect and without Express.

Comment: It probably needs another question. Anyway I'm accepting your answer to this since it works. Thanks!